# how to get dynamically created object inserted into another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning!
i have two dynamically created objects using form fields values. They are object literals which look like this:

```js
var courses = {};
course['name'] = $('#course').val();
var students = {};
students['first'] = $('#first_name').val();
students['last'] = $('#last_name').val();
students['age'] = $('age').val();
```

I would like to insert them in a single object literal `var person= {}`
i need the two objects into one because I need to stringify it and send via ajax to my process page. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can populate an object as you are creating it:

```js
var persons = {
    courses: {
        name: $('#course').val(),
    },
    students: {
        name: $('#first_name').val(),
        last: $('#last_name').val(),
        age: $('#age').val(),
    },
};
```

If you want to use the objects that you already have then you can do so:

```js
var persons = {
    courses: courses,
    students: students,
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Please I would like to know if it creates new objects with new values automatically or if I should do it otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a object with the 2 objects like:

```
var data = {courses:courses,students:students};
```

or you can append one to the other

```
students['courses'] = courses;
```

Answer (score 1):

And what's the problem? 
Just place these objects into your object and then you can serialize it e.g. to JSON and send via ajax:

```
var person = {}
person.course = {};
person.student = {};

person.course['name'] = "Course 1";
person.student['first'] = "Vasya";
person.student['last'] = "Pupkin";
person.student['age'] = "26";
```

If you want multiple *students*, you should use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Here we create an array with 3 objects, each represents a *student*:

```
var person = {}
person.course = {};
person.students = [{},{},{}];

person.course['name'] = "Course 1";
person.students[0]['first'] = "Vasya";
person.students[0]['last'] = "Pupkin";
person.students[0]['age'] = "26";

person.students[1]['first'] = "Petya";
person.students[1]['last'] = "Vasechkin";
person.students[1]['age'] = "30";

person.students[2]['first'] = "Vasiliy";
person.students[2]['last'] = "Alibabaevich";
person.students[2]['age'] = "40";
```

You can do the same thing with *courses*.

But in this case the name **person** for the object that contains all this data a bit confusing, because it contains multiple students. You should give meaningful names for your variables.

Comment: When I create the objects this way, the final object contains only the first two objects. I would like to create many objects (students) with the same structure but with different values . I do not know how to create all my students at once and include it to the final object that I stringify and send. Could you please help me?